# How to retrieve string from UserDefaults in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have a textField for the user to input their name.

```
 @IBAction func nameTextField(sender: AnyObject) {

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setObject("\(nameTextField)", forKey: "userNameKey")


}
```

Then I recall the inputted name in ViewDidLoad with:

```
 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("userNameKey")

    nameLabel.text = "userNameKey"
```

What am I doing wrong? Result is simply "userNameKey" every time. I'm new to this, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to assign the result returned by [nsuserdefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html) method to your nameLabel.text. Besides that [stringForKey](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/stringForKey:) returns an optional so I recommend using the [nil coalescing operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html) to return an empty string instead of nil to prevent a crash if you try to load it before assigning any value to the key.

```
func string(forKey defaultName: String) -> String?
```

> Return Value For string values, the string associated with the
>   specified key. For number values, the string value of the number.
>   Returns nil if the default does not exist or is not a string or number
>   value.

**Special Considerations
The returned string is immutable, even if the value you originally set was a mutable string.**

You have to as follow:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set("textToSave", forKey: "userNameKey")

nameLabel.text = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userNameKey")  ?? ""
```

Comment: Great! It works. But that just gives me the name - anyway to do do something like nameLabel.text = "Hey (userNameKey)!" ? Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is:

```
@IBAction func nameTextField(sender: AnyObject) {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.set(yourTextField.text, forKey: "userNameKey")
}
```

And later in the viewDidLoad:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

let yourValue = defaults.string(forKey: "userNameKey")

nameLabel.text = yourValue
```